# Проблемы с EntityFramework+SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Пытаюсь подружить EF6 и SQLite базу данных. Создал модель и контекст данных. DBContext генерирует следующий SQL код:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[NAME] AS [NAME], 
    [Extent1].[ENTRYNUMBER] AS [ENTRYNUMBER], 
    [Extent1].[TIME] AS [TIME], 
    [Extent1].[WORKFLOWENTRYNUMBER] AS [WORKFLOWENTRYNUMBER], 
    [Extent1].[FOLDERENTRYNUMBER] AS [FOLDERENTRYNUMBER], 
    [Extent1].[ISFAILED] AS [ISFAILED], 
    [Extent1].[ISCOPIED] AS [ISCOPIED], 
    [Extent1].[DURATION] AS [DURATION], 
    [Extent1].[PROCESSDURATION] AS [PROCESSDURATION], 
    [Extent1].[PRIORITY] AS [PRIORITY], 
    [Extent1].[TOTALCHARACTERS] AS [TOTALCHARACTERS], 
    [Extent1].[UNCERTAINCHARACTERS] AS [UNCERTAINCHARACTERS], 
    [Extent1].[PAGESAREA] AS [PAGESAREA], 
    [Extent1].[USERNAME] AS [USERNAME]
    FROM [dbo].[Jobs] AS [Extent1]
```

Но мне нужно FROM [Jobs] без [dbo]. Как можно на это повлиять? спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная схема в SQLite называется main. Ее надо указать или отдельно для каждой сущности:

```
[Table("Jobs", Schema = "main")]
public class Job {
```

Или сразу для всего контекста:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder b) {
    b.HasDefaultSchema("main");
```

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо. Но теперь другая проблема: 
var jobs = db.Jobs.ToList(); возвращает пустой список, хотя если вручную выполнить сгенерированный Entity Фреймворком запрос, то он работает корректно.

Comment: @ЯкутинАртем один из принципов работы SO заключается в одном вопросе и одном ответе. Если у вас появился новый, пусть и вытекший из старого вопрос -- просто задайте новый вопрос. Если считаете нужным, можете дать там ссылку на старый (этот) вопрос.