# Проблемы с EntityFramework + SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite, entity-framework

Пытаюсь подружить EF6 и SQLite базу данных. Создал модель и контекст данных.

```
 [Table("JOBS", Schema = "main")]
    public class Job
    {
        [Column("ID")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Column("NAME")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column("ENTRYNUMBER")]
        public int EntryNumber { get; set; }
        [Column("TIME")]
        public int Time { get; set; }
        [Column("WORKFLOWENTRYNUMBER")]
        public int WorkflowEntryNumber { get; set; }
        [Column("FOLDERENTRYNUMBER")]
        public int FolderEntryNumber { get; set; }
        [Column("ISFAILED")]
        public int IsFailed { get; set; }
        [Column("ISCOPIED")]
        public int IsCopied { get; set; }
        [Column("DURATION")]
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        [Column("PROCESSDURATION")]
        public int ProcessDuration { get; set; }
        [Column("PRIORITY")]
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        [Column("TOTALCHARACTERS")]
        public int TotalCharacters { get; set; }
        [Column("UNCERTAINCHARACTERS")]
        public int UncertainCharacters { get; set; }
        [Column("PAGESAREA")]
        public int PagesArea { get; set; }
        [Column("USERNAME")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

    }
    public class Context:DbContext
    {
        public Context():base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=C:\ProgramData\ABBYY Recognition Server 4.0\RS4WF\Jobs\JobsLog\temp\JobsLogTable.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"  type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

В итоге при попытке загрузить объекты получаю пустую коллекцию, хотя база данных заполнена.

```
 var db = new Context();
 db.Jobs.Load();            
 var jobs=db.Jobs.Local.ToList();
```

Вот начало [Проблемы с EntityFramework+SQLite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772717/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-entityframeworksqlite/772723?noredirect=1#comment1207062_772723)

Comment: `Data Source=`? Я так помню должно быть `Filename=`

Comment: Не помогло, хотя, видимо, проблема именно где-то в app.config, потому что если указываю неверный путь к файлу, то результат выполнения не изменяется.

Comment: ты testconnection сделал, все ок?

Comment: Обычными SQL запросами со строкой подключения 'Data Source ={Path.Combine(tempPath, "JobsLogTable.db")}; Provider = System.Data.SQLite' все работает

Comment: Попробуй добавить к строке подключения `Read Only=True;FailIfMissing=True;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С базами данных не работал раньше, решил попробовать, выбрал sqlite ef6, так же были проблемы с ним, в особенности с настройками в app.config.

DatabaseContext и репозитории находятся в отдельной библиотеке.
Решил все проблемы убрав настройки из app.config (в библиотеке он не нужен) в отдельный класс:

```
public class DatabaseConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public DatabaseConfiguration()
    {
        SqlConnectionFactory sqlConnectionFactory =
            new SqlConnectionFactory("System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework");
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(sqlConnectionFactory);

        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite", (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices)));
    }
}
```

Описание DatabaseContext:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(DatabaseConfiguration))]
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

Тогда в app.config главной сборки проекта (console/wpf/и т.д.) нужно всего лишь добавить путь к базе данных:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Database.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

А попробуй так сделать по аналоги, без Load

```
        var fa = new ModelFaContext();
        var list1 = fa.goods.Where (i => i.guid != null).Select(i=>i).ToList();
```

Comment: var jobs=db.Jobs.ToArray() дает тот же самый результат.